# Select elements contain no specified son node with pure js

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectors-api

```js
$("td:not(:has(input))").each(function ( index,element){
console.log(index);
console.log(element);
console.log($(this).text())});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text">test3</td>
    <td><input type="text">test4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to select all `td` which contain no son node `input`,that is to say,what i expect is as below:

```
<td>test1</td>
<td>test2</td>
```

It's verified by jquery's select expression `td:not(:has(input))` ,it works fine.
There is a famous webpage `You Don't Need jQuery!` and a book `Beyond jQuery`.

**[You Don't Need jQuery!](https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery)**

Let's try with pure javascript.

Can we fulfill the work with pure js?

Comment: As the duplicate of your previous question states, there is no native CSS selector (also used by the Selectors API) solution to this. If you want a pure JavaScript solution you need to loop through the cells and manually check if each one has an input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `:has` selector alternative in native JS, you could do this by looping through all the `td`'s and check manually:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(function(element) {
  if (!element.querySelector('input')) {
    console.log(element.innerText);
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>test2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text">test3</td>
    <td><input type="text">test4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It is difficult to replace jQuery with pure js,`td:not(:has(input))` is more elegant than loop and check again in js.